# hadith on disturbing someone who is asleep

Tags: hadith, sunnah

assalamualaikum, can anyone please answer whether there is any hadith on disturbing someone who is asleep
The Prophet (صلى الله عليه وسلم) also said:
"Whoever is deprived of gentleness is deprived of all sorts of goodness"
(Bukhari) is this isthe hadith . please reply

Answer (score 2):

Islamic books on manners refer to the following hadith as guidance on not disturbing the sleeping person (small portion of a longer hadith):

> ...Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) said: Milk these for us. So we milked them and every person amongst us drank his share and we set aside the share of Allah's Apostle (ﷺ). (It was his habit) to come during the night and greet (the people present there) in a manner that would not wake up one in sleep but make one who was awake hear it... ([Sahih Muslim 2055](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2055a)).

That's the general kindness and consideration for sleeping people.

A specific exception is waking the sleeping person for prayer [which is a good deed].

> "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'May Allah (SWT) have mercy on a man who gets up at night and prays, then he wakes his wife and she prays, and if she refuses he sprinkles water in her face. And may Allah (SWT) have mercy on a woman who gets up at night and prays, then she wakes her husband and prays, and if he refuses she sprinkles water in his face.'" ([Al Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai:1610) & others)

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته